# Durability of storage in second generation google cloud sql

Tags: storage, google-cloud-sql

How durable should I expect data for a Google Cloud SQL instance to be? Just a single instance, with the high-availability option disabled.

AWS explicitly mention that Amazon Aurora data is stored in six copies over multiple availability zones. Is any such information available for Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You may not find any such information for GCP because Aurora is a storage engine native to Amazon. It can be used with MySQL or PostgreSQL.

You only have three(3) options here:

### OPTION #1

You need to read the [Amazon Documentation on Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) and try to locate the same storage options and features in CloudSQL. Thoroughly scour the GCP Documentation for any new storage options for CloudSQL similar to Aurora.

### OPTION #2

You should also focus on what Google provides for CloudSQL High Availability

- [Overview of the High Availability Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability)
- [Configuring an Instance for High Availability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha)
- [Instance Locations](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-locations)

### OPTION #3

You may want to consider just customizing a solution with ComputeEngine instances with MySQL manually installed and create frequent snapshots of your data folder (which should contain InnoDB tables only along with binary logs). Additional instances (at least 1) for setting up MySQL Replication slaves may be need to still have additional HA.

Comment: Availability is not my main concern, durability is. I can live with some downtime, but cannot live with dataloss. That makes a single MySQL compatible Aurora instance look interesting. If I use googles high availability option to improve durability it will also double the cost. So I am looking for information on how durable storage below CloudSQL is. That is the information I have not been able to find in Googles documentation.